# How to override copy and paste in richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

How can I override the copy/paste functions in a Richtextbox C# application.
Including ctrl-c/ctrl-v  and right click copy/paste.

It's WPF richtextBox.

Comment: for Windows Forms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618162/detecting-if-paste-event-occurred-inside-a-rich-text-box

for WPF see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061475/paste-event-in-a-wpf-textbox

Comment: @Davide, the WPF link adds a handler, but it doesnt override it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To override the command functions:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
  if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
  {
    //your implementation
    return true;
  } 
  else if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V))
  {
    //your implementation
    return true;
  } 
  else 
  {
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
  }
}
```

And right-clicking is not supported in a Winforms RichTextBox

--EDIT--

Realized too late this was a WPF question. To do this in WPF you will need to attach a custom Copy and Paste handler:

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(myRichTextBox, MyPasteCommand);
DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(myRichTextBox, MyCopyCommand);

private void MyPasteCommand(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}

private void MyCopyCommand(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do that in WPF ?

Comment: @EdiwnThe WPF stuff you have, adds a handler but doesnt override the main cop/paste ones, they are still being called

Comment: @raym0nd: You could add 'e.CancelCommand();' to prevent the default copy/pasting...

Comment: @EdwindeKoning For Windows Forms, this approach might work for CTRL+V, but not SHIFT+INSERT, which is also a standard paste key-combination. Of course, using your example, it'd be easier to extend the solution to support this.

Answer (score 4):

What about Cut while using Copy and Paste Handlers? 
When you have your custom implementation of OnCopy and you handle it by

```
e.Handled = true;
e.CancelCommand();
```

OnCopy is also called when doing Cut - I can't find the way to find out whether method was called to perform copy or cut.

Comment: Me too, I dont know if it is Copy or Cut

Answer (score 2):

I used this:
//doc.Editor is the RichtextBox

```
 DataObject.AddPastingHandler(doc.Editor, new DataObjectPastingEventHandler(OnPaste));
 DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(doc.Editor, new DataObjectCopyingEventHandler(OnCopy));



    private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    { 

    }
    private void OnCopy(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```