# How to convert Word Equation to an Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, equation

I want when i Copy/Paste an equation on a RichTexyBox(wpf/win) I Convert it to an Image.How can I do it?Or Can I get it from clipboard as an image ?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to look into [attaching your own paste handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243804) in which you perform your conversions.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie How can I extract Image from clipboard to System.Drawing.Image object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MathType for export all equations of docoment to images:
http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/
And before install MathType try to save a document as web page and look inside created folder.