# Check if paste into textbox with max length will truncate clipboard contents

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several `textbox` fields in my `WPF` application that have max character lengths set.

***The Problem:***

If you paste a string that is too long, then it truncates that string to fit the max length.

***The Question:***

How can I check that on pasting to a `textbox` control if the character count for contents that is being pasted is greater than the max character length set for that `textbox`?

Comment: Not sure about WPF, but in Windows Forms you would hook the message loop an intercept `WM_PASTE` messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Paste Event in a WPF TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061475/paste-event-in-a-wpf-textbox)

You can use a solution similar to the accepted answer, where you add a paste handler, and compare the `MaxLength` of the TextBox to the contents of the clipboard:

```
var tb = sender as TextBox;
var text = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
if(text > tb.MaxLength) {
    //Do whatever it is you want to do
}
```