# Textbox without special chars

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, textbox

I want my textbox to never accept special chars.
Only accepts space,numbers and letters.
I found this code for Presskey event:

```
private void rsNameTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back && !char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
        }
```

But it doesnt work when someone paste something in the textbox. How can I make a textChanged event equivalent?

I tried replacing the not accepted chars for "" with this function but its not working.Its showing any chars when I paste and for some reason its erasing the default initial text "text1":

```
 private void rsNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[\s\dA-Za-z]+$");
            rsNameTextBox.Text = reg.Replace(rsNameTextBox.Text,"");
        }
```

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061475/paste-event-in-a-wpf-textbox. Note if you try checking data with the PreviewTextInput command you will find that space, backspace & delete do not cause an event - you need to check that with the PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: Note - to ignore the pasted input you need to call _e.CancelCommand();_

Answer (score 0):

> why you are not using `ShortcutsEnabled` propety of the `TextBox` you
>   want to prevent cut,copy and paste features.

and then you can use your code in `rsNameTextBox_KeyPress`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113722/how-to-disable-copy-paste-and-delete-features-on-a-textbox-using-c-sharp) is the link ,How to prevent paste features in Window Form Application.